# App Architecture: How to use just what you need from a MongoDB response

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I have a simple node application with typescript connected to MongoDB

```js
import mongoose, { ObjectId } from 'mongoose'
import moment from 'moment'
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test123'

enum Asset {
    ES = 'ES',
    ZB = 'ZB',
    CL = 'CL',
    ZN = 'ZN',
    _6E = '_6E'
}

interface RawMarketDataLog {
    _id: ObjectId,
    SessionIndex: number,
    MarketDataType: number,
    Ask: number,
    Bid: number,
    Price: number,
}

const main = async () => {
    mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    const db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', async () => {
        console.log('we are connected to mongoDB!')
        const inputs = {
            asset: Asset.ES,
            startDate: moment('01/03/2021', "DD-MM-YYYY"),
            endDate: moment('02/03/2021', "DD-MM-YYYY")
        }
        console.log('I finished to take inputs')
        const loadMarketDataByAssetAndDate = async (asset: Asset, startDate: moment.Moment, endDate: moment.Moment,) => {
            for (let d = moment(startDate); d.isSameOrBefore(endDate); d.add(1, 'day')) {
                const collectionName = `market_data_${asset}_${d.format('YYYY_MM_DD')}`
                console.log(collectionName)
                const fetchedCollection: RawMarketDataLog[] = await db.collection(collectionName).find({}).toArray()
                console.log(fetchedCollection)
            }
            console.log('I finish the loop')
        }

    });
}

main()
```

as you can see in the code I have multiple collections that are sorted by asset & date,
now each collection contains lots of logs which look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a7d9f7ff54ed397d650976"),
    "SessionIndex" : NumberLong(1),
    "MarketDataType" : 2,
    "Ask" : 0.0,
    "Bid" : 0.0,
    "Price" : 2388.0,
    "Volume" : NumberLong(51),
    "Internal_Date" : ISODate("2017-04-28T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "Internal_ExchangeTime" : "08:30:00.0160000"
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is this, I don't need all that key: value pair in each log JSON response,
I only need some of them, so I want to create a modal that looks like `RawMarketDataLog` in the code above, and to save only have I need, also when I expose it in an API I want to be able to give different values as well, what is the design pattern for this kind of app?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you're trying to address here is related to the creation of a custom object. Since you asked for a design pattern, I would suggest you could either go with something similar to `Data Access Object` Pattern with a `JSON API Serializer` or using just plain `Builder Pattern` to build your `RawMarketDataLog` object. Each of them has its own merits in how you're trying to designing the solution. You can read more about them on the internet but there are few points that I'd like to elaborate.

- With Data Access Object pattern you get a concrete object with all the fields you require. It acts as an abstraction between your mongodb documents or mongoose schema and your application code so that your code looks much cleaner. You can then have a `JSON API Serializer` in the API which will be responsible for exposing only required fields from your Data Access Object.
- With Builder Pattern, you have the flexibility of building the `RawMarketDataLog` object as customized as you need in your code so that the object has only the required fields in it. This will make your code a bit complex and not so easy to read.

There is no concrete answer to this question but I'd go with a `Data Access Object` and a `JSON API Serializer` in this case.

Comment: Isn't mongoose a Model already "Data Access Object" and Serializer? Straining my brain trying to see how Builder fits into the picture.

Comment: @semisecure edited my answer to give a bit more clarity on how to use the patterns specified.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to:

> How to use just what you need from a MongoDB response?

Mongoose supports [projections](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) just like MongoDB does. If you need something more, you'd need to put another adaptor layer over your mongoose Models to do filtering.

In Typescript you can use the [ts-transformer-keys](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys) transformer plugin to pluck the keys out of an interface then use that in the select param to `find()`. Note you have to use `ttypescript` (ttsc) compiler not `typescript` (tsc) because typescript doesn't currently support transformers (see the github link above for details on configuring).

*Example:*

```js
import { Schema, model, default as mongoose } from 'mongoose';
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
  await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

  interface ITest {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
  }
  const TestSchema = new Schema({
    a: String,
    b: String,
    c: String,
    d: String,
    e: String,
  });
  const Test = model('Test', TestSchema);
  
  await Test.insertMany([
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
  ]);
  
  const res = await Test.find({}, keys<ITest>());
  console.log(res);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit())
  .catch(e => { console.error(e); process.exit(); });
```

*Gives:*

```
[
  { _id: 60b22b6abf355a7184a24140, a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' },
  { _id: 60b22b6abf355a7184a24141, a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' },
  { _id: 60b22b6abf355a7184a24142, a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }
]
```

If this is too much, just hand code the list of keys and stash them next to your models somewhere - bit hacky but I would probably go with that TBH.